# I want to FaceTime, but can only WhatsApp

Tags: ios, facetime, whatsapp.app

I've installed WhatsApp on my phone, and now I only have the option to make WhatsApp video calls - not FaceTime.

Sadly, they almost never work (for some reason??). When I use my partner's phone, FaceTime always works.

How do I make a FaceTime video Call rather than WhatsApp?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Press and hold` the buttons that are currently labeled as `WhatsApp` and it should give you a choice on which App you call from for this contact.

It should remember your choice after selecting.

Comment: Thanks! But when I do that the only option I have is WhatsApp...

Comment: to call a person on Facetime (s)he must have an AppleID registered on icloud at that moment... i.e. you could also use messages (with the blue baloon) to message her/him. Also, when Facetime is available it appears as a added row to the person's contacts. So it can be available for a contact and not to be for another.

Answer (score 1):

You could have someone make a facetime call to you to be sure your account is set up properly. If it is, you might need to remove WhatsApp and then verify you can make an outbound facetime call to the person in question.

When that’s all sorted, reinstall What’s App and be sure you check the preferences and settings when it asks to be integrated in the calling experience.

This likely is a fault in the registration for FaceTime on your or your friend’s contact details since both apps should co-exist and let you long press to choose which to use on any given contact by design.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlink your account for google and just leave the iCloud account open  it work this way for me